# Xcode 10 Error on compile time :Segmentation fault 11

Tags: compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, xcode10, swift4.2

I am working on an iOS application. When I was using Xcode 9.4.1 and maximum deployment target was iOS 11.x. Application is working fine for Xcode 9.4.1 and iOS below iOS 12.

But when I tried to run my same code on iOS 12 then I have to run this on Xcode 10.

I am getting this compile time error in my code:

[image]

I have changed Swift version in project and target :
[image]

[image]

```
1.  While emitting SIL for 'fetchConsumerRecommendations(completionHandler:failureHandler:)' at /Users/ajeetsharma/Desktop/Pune/Food/Food/FirebaseManager/FirebaseManager.swift:3472:5
2.  While silgen emitFunction SIL function "@$S4Food15FirebaseManagerC28fetchConsumerRecommendations17completionHandler07failureH0yySaySSGc_ys5Error_pSgctFZ".
 for 'fetchConsumerRecommendations(completionHandler:failureHandler:)' at /Users/ajeetsharma/Desktop/Pune/Food/Food/FirebaseManager/FirebaseManager.swift:3472:5
3.  While silgen closureexpr SIL function "@$S4Food15FirebaseManagerC28fetchConsumerRecommendations17completionHandler07failureH0yySaySSGc_ys5Error_pSgctFZySo19FIRDocumentSnapshotCSg_AItcfU_".
 for expression at [/Users/ajeetsharma/Desktop/Pune/Food/Food/FirebaseManager/FirebaseManager.swift:3477:285 - line:3527:9] RangeText="{ (documentSnapshot, error) in


            if error == nil {

                if documentSnapshot == nil{


                    return
                }
                if (documentSnapshot?.exists)!{

                    print("Consumer Recommendations - \(describing: documentSnapshot?.data())")

                    let dictOnboarding:NSDictionary = (documentSnapshot?.data())! as NSDictionary

                    if dictOnboarding["Recommendation"] != nil{


                        print("\(dictOnboarding.allKeys)")

                        completionHandler(dictOnboarding["Recommendation"] as! [String])


                    }
                    else{

                        print("\(dictOnboarding.allKeys)")

                        completionHandler(dictOnboarding.allKeys as! [String])


                    }

                }
                else {


                    completionHandler([])

                }

            }
            else{

                failureHandler(error)

            }


        }"
error: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Check wether any single generic class which inherited from the same protocol twice or not.And clean your project. Hope it will work. Also please add what and all you have tried.So that it will make us clear.